# proof by induction of $n^n\le(n!)^2\ \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that:
$$n^n \le (n!)^2\ \ , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$$

my attempt was:
$$(n+1)^{n-1} \le n^n \le (n!)^2\ \ , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$$
which comes down to $$\ \ \ \ \ (n+1)^{n-1} \le n^n \ , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$$
which i still can't figure out a proof for.

Comment: How would knowing $(n+1)^{n-1} \le n^n$ help you in any way to show that $n^n \le (n!)^2$.  Showing that some things are less than X can not in any way tell us whether different things are larger than X.

Comment: I wouldn't do that by induction, personally. It's a lot easier to show that $m(n-m)\geq n$ for $1\leq m\leq n$, and thus the squared factorial is larger.

Comment: @fleablood I know by inductive hypothesis that $n^n \le (n!)^2\ $ so we have to prove that $(n+1)^{n+1}\le (n+1)! \ $ which equals to $(n+1)^2 (n+1)^{n-1}\le (n+1)^2(n!)^2 \ $ simplified  $(n+1)^{n-1}\le (n!)^2 \ $ so proving the stricter condition that $(n+1)^{n-1}\le n^n$ implies the inductive step.

Comment: I suppose you could prove *that* by induction.  If course if it is true you have $(2n)^0 \le 2n-1 \le (2n-1)^2 \le ...... \le (n+2)^{n-2} \le (n+1)^{n-1} \le n^n$ which may or may not be useful and may or may not be easy.  Actually that mean it'd suffice to show $m^{n+1} \ge (m+1)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove 
$$\ \ \ \ \ (n+1)^{n-1} \le n^n \ , \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$$
it is equivalent to prove 
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\le1,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$$
which is a decreasing function of $n$. As $n$ increases from 1 to infinity, $\frac{1}{n+1}$ goes to $0$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ goes to constant $e$.

The last argument can be proved as follows: Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, and take the ratio of series terms
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{\frac{1}{n+2}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}}=\left(\frac{(n+2)n}{(n+1)(n+1)}\right)^n=\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+2n+1}\right)^n<1.$$

Comment: It is trivial to prove that $\frac{1}{n+1}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\le1,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$ by taking log of it:

Comment: Correction: by taking log is not directly helping the proof but for the transformation of the expression forms.

Comment: This conclusion is very useful. The variants are: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\le n+1$ or $(n-1)\ln(n+1)-n\ln{n}\le0$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^+$

Comment: thank, i've come to the same conclusion yesterday that since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\le 4$ and for every $n \le 3$ the statement is true

Comment: Thanks for the answer,<br>I've come to the same conclusion yesterday that since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\le n+1$ for all $n \le 3$  and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \le 4\ $ is true $\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \ $.<br> As for the conclusion i needed it to prove that $\ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$ (i didn't know you could only edit for 5 min and shift+enter would post)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: look at the ratios

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n} \\
\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(n!)^2}.$$

Upon checking the base case (easy), induction tells us that it is enough to show the first ratio is smaller than the second. But these two both simplify nicely.